# Boundary Classification for Particular Sets

Tags: general-topology

I'm asked to classify each of the following sets as either *open*, *closed*, *neither*, or *both*:

(a) $\begin{Bmatrix}\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\end{Bmatrix}\leadsto both$

(b) $\mathbb{N}$

(c) $\mathbb{Q}$

(d) $\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1}\pmatrix{0,\frac{1}{n}}=(0,0)=\varnothing\leadsto closed$

(e) $\begin{Bmatrix}x:\lvert x-5\rvert\leq\frac{1}{2}\end{Bmatrix}\leadsto closed$

(f) $\{x:x^2>0\}\leadsto both$

---

In particular, I'm focusing on parts (a), (d), (e), and (f).

Answer (score 3):

Recall that a set $O$ is *open* if every point $x \in O$ has a neighborhood contained in $O$, while a set $F$ is closed if it contains all of its limit points.

Now for some hints on how to proceed on the four parts you mentioned:

For (a), note that $0$ is a limit point not contained in the set, and $1$ has no neighborhood contained in the set.

For (d), note the $\emptyset$ is vacuously both open and closed.

For (e), you're correct. Another way to write the set is $[4.5, 5.5]$.

For (f), $0$ is a limit point of the set.

Answer (score 2):

A subset $A$ of $\Bbb R$ is open if for each $x\in A$ there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq A$, where $B(x,\epsilon)=(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$. It’s closed if $\Bbb R\setminus A$ is open.

- Is there an open interval around $\frac12$ that lies entirely within the set $\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$? There is not, so this set cannot be open.
- Is $\Bbb R\setminus\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ open? No, because $0\in\Bbb R\setminus\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$, but no open interval around $0$ is contained entirely within $\Bbb R\setminus\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$.

For (d) you’re half right: $\varnothing$ is a closed set. However, it’s also open: the empty set is always an open set and a closed set, in every topological space.

Your answer to (e) is correct: the set is simply the closed interval $\left[\frac92,\frac{11}2\right]$.

Look again at (f): **every** real number except $0$ is in that set, so the set is $(\leftarrow,0)\cup(0,to)$. That’s certainly open, but is it really closed? Its complement is $\{0\}$; is $\{0\}$ really an open set?

Looking ahead, for (c) you might want to ask yourself whether either $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ contains **any** non-empty open interval.

Answer (score 1):

*Hints*:

*(a)* Is $0$ a limit point of $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$? What is an example of a neighborhood containing $1\in \{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ contained entirely in $\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$?

*(d)* The $\emptyset$ is both open and closed in $\mathbb{R}$ (it is vacuously deemed open by convention/definition and it is closed because, well, what can possibly be a limit point of $\emptyset$?!)

*(e)* You're correct

*(f)* The set is $(-\infty,0)\cup (0,\infty)$. Is $0$ a limit point of this set?

I hope this helps!

Comment: I think that for (d), the *more* correct answer is both.

Comment: Why is that? Explain...

Comment: @AmiteshDatta (e) should be (f).

Comment: Thanks @T.Bongers; you're absolutely right, of course. I noticed this as soon as I posted my answer but my computer wasn't permitting me to edit it (although I have done so just now!).

Comment: Thanks @Loie for pointing out the other typo!

Comment: @AmiteshDatta No problem - thanks for your (as usual) very nice answer.

Comment: Hi @T.Bongers, your answer is great too (it's also more detailed than mine and posted earlier)! I would really like to upvote it except that I always exhaust my daily upvote quota well before the sun rises on Stack Exchange again on a new GMT day. However, I'll certainly upvote it when I next get the opportunity!

Comment: Also, @T.Bongers, thanks for your kind words! I've certainly noticed that your many contributions to this site have been excellent as well. I had been meaning to tell you this for a while so let me do so now!

Comment: @AmiteshDatta Thank's a lot :)